# How to redirect without changing link to another link in .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am try to access another website through my website. And i use .htaccess redirect code to do that but it is not done.

i want to redirect https://web.karlosms.com to http://36.255.3.40:80 without changing the url.

I tried to use this code but it is not working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^web.karlosms.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://36.255.3.40:80/$1 [P]
```

It show the error:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.

Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

please Help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, did my answer help at all? Please kindly provide feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rewrite to a remote server.

You'll need to use a proxy directive to achieve that, which is probably not ideal, but the only solution to keep the initial URL.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html

Additionally, you'll need to fix what happens on the remote server (you shouldn't end up on a 403, even when redirecting), but why don't you make `web.karlosms.com` to `36.255.3.40` directly and define the proper virtualhost on this remote server?

It seems like there's no particular port or folder mapping between the 2 so you could deliver everything from the final server. Having a proxy in between is convoluted.